# django orm how to update calculate data using only one query

Tags: python, django

i create one feature about item_buy data

here is my ORM class

```
class BuyData(models.Model):
    buy_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    refund_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    refund_rate = models.FloatField(default=0.0, help_test='refund_count / buy_count')
```

when i create a function about `refund` i want update my BuyData model

like

```
def refund():
    buy_data_queryset.update(
        refund_count = F('refund_count') + 1
    )
    buy_data_queryset.update(
        refund_rate = F('refund_count') / F('buy_count') * 100
    )
```

but i think this way is not good because when this function called a lot of time per second, may be this 2 step queries raise some problem...

so i found some document, and changed like this

```
def refund():
    with transaction.atomic():
        buy_data_queryset.update(
            refund_count = F('refund_count') + 1
        )
        buy_data_queryset.update(
            refund_rate = F('refund_count') / F('buy_count') * 100
        )
```

i think this way is good. but i want to know that solve this problem using only one query

i know this is not a solution

```
def refund():
    # not a solution
    # because if refund_count is 100 and buy_count is 1000
    # i want to change my refund_rate = 101 / 1000
    # not 100 / 1000
    buy_data_queryset.update(
        refund_count = F('refund_count') + 1
        refund_rate = F('refund_count') / F('buy_count') * 100
    )
```

please give me some advice thank you :))

Comment: are you trying this in models.py or in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update multiple fields at once:

```py
>>> Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010).update(comments_on=False, headline='This is old')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

or in your case:

```py
buy_data_queryset.update(
        refund_count = F('refund_count') + 1,
        refund_rate = F('refund_count') / F('buy_count') * 100
    )
```

Comment: Hi @dack, thank you about ur advice! but i think this way is not a solution because when `refund_count = 100` and `buy_count = 1000`, refund_count will become 101( +1) but refund_rate still calculate `100 / 1000` but i want to `101/1000` thank you :)

Comment: Just add the +1 in the second line then. 